# WordPress - Update permalink automatically after posting an update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am calculating custom title for a product using WooCommerce add product page. After the user post product's information, title is generated and saved by a save_post filter hook.

```
add_filter('save_post', 'modify_post_title', '99', 1);
function modify_post_title($post_id)
{
    // some logic to form a new $title
    // ...

    if (!empty($title)) {
        // update the title in database
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_title' => $title), array('ID' => $post_id));     

        // UPDATE PERMALINK   
    }
}
```

I need to know what function to use to re-generate the permalink after updating title.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'custom_slug_change', 50, 2 );
function custom_slug_change( $data, $postarr ) {
    //Check for the  post statuses you want to avoid
    if ( !in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {           
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Would you please add above code in your `functions.php` ?

Comment: It worked perfectly when for existing posts. But for new post it is not working.

Comment: @Hamid We checked from ourside and it's working fine. Could you please re-check properly?

Comment: Did you mean when you create new product and save it? Then you have to change product title and your product permalink is not changed? Am I right?

Comment: I mean, when I create a new product, I just give a dummy title, then fill other attributes. Then, I click publish, a new title is generated by the above code and permalink still not updated. Then, I click Update button and here your code works and permalink is changed.

Comment: Could you please remove your code in your `functions.php`. ? And after check it.

In other words please comment this line `add_filter('save_post', 'modify_post_title', '99', 1);` in your `functions.php`.

Comment: yes, now it is working because the first permalink is generated by WordPress automatically. The problem is that I need to change it programmatically using the filter I commented out.

Comment: Is there any chance to have it working with new posts?

Comment: @Hamid I haven't any idea for why it's not working from your side. But I was tried my best.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: it succefully worked for me now, with help of your code. I just updated the following line in my filter:

    $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array('post_title' => $title, 'post_name' => sanitize_title($title)), array('ID' => $post_id));

and it did the job perfectly even for the new posts. Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can go with the **window.history.pushState** to maipulate the Browser History.

I think these may help you.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", surl[0]);
```

Comment: when should I call this javascript? Is there any PHP code that could do it?